# How to import hex dump into Wireshark with millisecond timestamps?

Tags: timestamp, hex, wireshark

I'm trying to import a text hex dump into wireshark with millisecond timestamps.

[I've read this page about how to do it, but it's not clear to me how to get millisecond timestamp granularity.](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChIOImportSection.html)

Here's my sample hex dump:

```
0.111
000000 00 e0 1e a7 05 6f 00 10 ........
000008 5a a0 b9 12 08 00 46 00 ........
000010 03 68 00 00 00 00 0a 2e ........
000018 ee 33 0f 19 08 7f 0f 19 ........
000020 03 80 94 04 00 00 10 01 ........
000028 16 a2 0a 00 03 50 00 0c ........
000030 01 01 0f 19 03 80 11 01 ........

1.222
000000 00 e0 1e a7 05 6f 00 10 ........
000008 5a a0 b9 12 08 00 46 00 ........
000010 03 68 00 00 00 00 0a 2e ........
000018 ee 33 0f 19 08 7f 0f 19 ........
000020 03 80 94 04 00 00 10 01 ........
000028 16 a2 0a 00 03 50 00 0c ........
000030 01 01 0f 19 03 80 11 01 ........

3.333
000000 00 e0 1e a7 05 6f 00 10 ........
000008 5a a0 b9 12 08 00 46 00 ........
000010 03 68 00 00 00 00 0a 2e ........
000018 ee 33 0f 19 08 7f 0f 19 ........
000020 03 80 94 04 00 00 10 01 ........
000028 16 a2 0a 00 03 50 00 0c ........
000030 01 01 0f 19 03 80 11 01 ........
```

If I enter "%S" as the Date/Time format when I do the import, I can get second granularity, which is nice - but everything beyond the second is truncated, so I don't get the actual milliseconds.  (Nanoseconds would be nice too, but I'll settle for milliseconds.)

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is impossible because wireshark uses [strptime(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strptime) to parse the timestamp and **strptime(3)** doesn't support milliseconds/fractions.

**Update 1:**

One possible solution is to write a custom dissector using Lua api supported by wireshark. More on that [here](https://wiki.wireshark.org/Lua/Dissectors).

Comment: Wireshark uses strptime to parse the timestamp, but it does recognize a trailing period in the format string and will treat the numbers following as fraction of a second.

Answer (score 2):

As is documented for `text2pcap` which is part of the Wireshark distribution, you need to include a trailing "period" in the format string if you want sub-second timestamps. E.g. `%H:%M:%S.` will parse `10:15:14.5476` correctly also in the Wireshark UI. In your case `%S.` should work.

From the `text2pcap` help:

> `-t <timefmt>`
>   treat the text before the packet as a date/time code; the specified argument is a format string of the sort supported by strptime.
>  
>   Example: The time `10:15:14.5476` has the format code `%H:%M:%S.`
>
> **NOTE: The subsecond component delimiter, '.', must be given, but no pattern is required; the remaining number is assumed to be fractions of a second.**
>
> NOTE: Date/time fields from the current date/time are used as the default for unspecified fields.

Comment: I found that Wireshark still doesn't understand that, I had to convert the hexdump using `text2pcap` first and then read the pcap to get timestamps. E.g. `/Applications/Wireshark.app/Contents/MacOS/text2pcap -t '%H:%M:%S.' -D -l 51 -n in.hex out.pcap`

Comment: Works great for me in Wireshark 3.2.3, no need to run text2pcap separately.

Comment: @jpa You should have used @DarkDust in front, otherwise he won't get notified of your comment ;-) And you are correct, but so was he. There was in fact a bug in Wireshark in older versions as the app used a different parser code than `text2pcap`. This bug has been reported and fixed by making the app use the same parser code as `text2pcap` about a year ago.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think it is relevant to DarkDust now 1.5 years later, just added a comment for anyone else who ends up here from Google like me :) But thanks for the details!